# Vagrant with VMware ESXi Provider

Tags: vmware-esxi, vagrant

I am attempting to work with Vagrant and the vagrant-vsphere plugin to deploy machines to my VMware ESXi server. Has anyone had any luck in getting this to work?  I realize that vagrant-vsphere is still 0.0.1 though and there are bound to be bugs.

Specifially, Vagrant and vagrant-vsphere appear to fail during the vsphere connection, however, SSH and CLI access is enabled and the vSphere powershell is able to connect without an issue.

INFO warden: Calling action: # 
ERROR warden: Error occurred: VagrantPlugins::VSphere::Errors::VSphereError

The hostd log file on the ESXi server shows the Vagrant doing an SearchIndex query.

Answer (score 1):

It's available with a plugin.

List of plugins for Vagrant are there: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/wiki/Available-Vagrant-Plugins

And there, it's the plugin for vagrant with vsphere as a provider: https://github.com/nsidc/vagrant-vsphere/ . It's support the last to date version of Vagrant 1.6.3 .

Comment: Late to the game, but I think OP was asking about ESXi specifically. Does this work directly against an ESXi server or do you need VSphere? I'm trying to to create and configure servers for a lab environment on the cheap and would like to use vagrant to target a server running the free ESXi hypervisor in my network.

Comment: Just found my answer at this link: http://blog.broez.com/vagrant-vsphere-centos-7/ vagrant-vsphere does NOT work with just ESXi. The remote management functionality is in VSphere.

Answer (score 1):

The Vagrant-vSphere plugin doesn't work with ESXi directly.   Specifically, you need to use the vagrant-vmware-esxi plugin.   A requirement is ovftool from vmware and ssh access (which looks like you've done already).

```
https://github.com/josenk/vagrant-vmware-esxi
```